# Rider ASP project can't be launched, but it works in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, rider

This is really odd.

I have both Rider and Visual Studio 2017. When I attempt to run the project from Visual Studio I have no issues. However as soon as I try to run the exact same project from Rider it says "this site can't be reached".

Rider throws no errors and the run job is not interrupted, however the site is just not available.

How can I debug this issue? Are there any missing drivers or anything other that might be the cause of this?

I wish I could provide more logs, however I am not sure where to look.

Rider version: 2018.1

Comment: Please specify the exact Rider version.

Comment: @PeterB added the version to the question

Comment: Simply because Rider uses its own IIS Express config file, https://blog.lextudio.com/secrets-behind-jetbrains-rider-and-iis-express-d2ad006301e1